# How to get the (current url + query string) using python code with urllib2?

Tags: python, url, urllib2

I need to read the current url with the query string which i used ?

Means i need to get the browser current address bar url..

Comment: Which browser are you expecting to get the URL from?  (e.g. Firefox, Chrome, etc.)  It sounds as if this isn't much to do with urllib2...

Comment: This question does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `urllib2.Request` object provides a `geturl()` method, which returns the full URL of a request. You may then pass it to [`urlparse.urlparse()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse), which splits a URL into six components of every URL. Then you may access the query part via `query` attribute.

An example:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> req = urlopen('http://capitalfm.com/?foo=bar')
>>> req.geturl()
'http://www.capitalfm.com/?foo=bar'
>>> url = urlparse(req.geturl())
>>> url.query
'foo=bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, if you are using urllib2, you already have the url handy.  In order to extract the query string from a URL you can use the handy [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) function in python 2 (the function has been moved to a different module in python 3).

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = 'www.example.com/file.php?id=2'
>>> urlparse("www.example.com/file.php?id=2").query
'id=2'
>>>
```